# Android material map

Tags: android

In [this google page](https://material.google.com/style/typography.html#typography-other-typographic-guidelines) they show a really nice material map : 
[image]

Is it possible to implement a map that looks the same in an Android App? For lollipop and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the basic Android SDK for Google Maps. It's easy to zoom, tilt and move the camera to show those 3D building wherever they are available.

Take a look at the official documentation for step by step instructions on how to get it to work: [Camera and View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views)